# How to consume com libraries for SQLSERVERSMO?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, c++-cli

I have created a com library by which I can discover the SQLVolumes using SMo namespace in VS2005.
Now I want to use this com library in VS2003 to discover the same sqlvolumes in another machine where vs2003 installed.

Can I use it like this? I have created a COM using version VS2005 and now i want to consume it in VS2003 is it possible?

I request you people not to mark this as a duplicate because I need effective answer.

```
using System;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using Microsoft.Win32;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

using System.Data;

public interface ICalculator

{

 void Show();

};

namespace ManagedDLL
{
    public class ManagedClass : ICalculator
    {

        public void Show()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("from managed class");
            Console.WriteLine("c# "); Console.WriteLine("c#");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string srvname,filepath; 

            //evaluates local instances of SQLSERVER
            dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
            Console.WriteLine("Local Instances are \n");
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"]);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                srvname = (string)dr["name"];

                Console.WriteLine("\nConnecting to Server " + srvname + "\n\nDiscovering Volumes...\n\nDiscovering Sql2005 Volumes for the Host " + srvname.ToLower() + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\nHostName   : " + srvname.ToLower() + "\n");
                Server srv = new Server(srvname);
                Console.WriteLine(" Server Name \n" + srv.Name);
                foreach( Database db in srv.Databases)
                {
                    filepath = db.PrimaryFilePath;
                    Console.WriteLine("File Path : " + filepath + "\\" + db.Name + ".mdf \n");
                    Console.WriteLine("File Path : " + filepath + "\\" + db.Name + ".ldf \n");
                }


            }//foreach


        }
    }

}
```

I have created a com library for this class, and I have to use this com library in vs2003 and one more thing is the smo namespace.

The above code is not supported by .net f/w 1.1. How to can i do like this?

While consuming I am getting the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x7c812a6b in Comssss.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error @ 0x0012fcbc.

Comment: Have you tested this class in C#? Does it work when called from a .net 2.0 exe? Also, where does it fail? on the call to EnumAvailableSqlServers?

Comment: yes.it works fine. i hav created it as com.i have used this com in smae vs2005 for another class. and get the exe.  when i run the exe in a vs2003 machine it shows it needs runtime and closes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have the .net 2 runtimes installed, VS2003 COM interop should work fine.

Are you having a specific problem doing this? If so can you tell us the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x7c812a6b in Comssss.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error @ 0x0012fcbc.


This is the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can't load two versions of the framework into the same process.
VS2003 is already using .NET 1.1, so you won't be able to load an in-proc COM component that needs .NET 2.0.

You may be able to use DCOM and have it out-proc.